# let $a_1=1$ and $a_n=\sin(a_{n-1})$, $n>1$ and $n \in N$ The Calculate the following Limit

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Let $a_1=1$ and $a_n=\sin(a_{n-1})$, $n>1$ and $n \in N$
> If $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{2{a_n}}-2^{1+a_n} \cdot 3^{a_n}+3^{2a_n}}{\cos(a_n)+1-e^{a_n}-e^{-a_n}}=l\quad$$
> Then calculate $l$

How to solve it without Using L'Hopital's Rule.

**My Approach:**

$$\begin{align}
a_2 &=\sin(a_1)\\
\implies a_2 &=\sin(1)\\
\implies a_3 &=\sin(\sin1)\\
\end{align}
$$
Similarly $a_n=\sin(\sin(\sin\sin(....(sin1))))$

Which will Approach to Zero for $n \to \ \infty$

$\implies$  $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$

Later I Replaced $a_n$ with $x$

So question changed to
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2^{x}-2^{1+x} \cdot 3^{x}+3^{2x}}{\cos(x)+1-e^{x}-e^{-x}}=l \implies \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(2^x-3^x)^2}{1+\cos(x)-e^x-e^{-x}}$$

How to solve it further without using L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: It may be (or not) useful to know that $a_n \sim \sqrt{3/n}$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe yes but i want to find exact value. Thanks

Comment: @mathophile There are any reasons that you don't want to use l'hopital's rule?

Comment: @NN2 No, There is not any reason for that I just want to avoid Using l'hopital's Rule.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :** when $x$ tends to $0$, you have

$$\frac{(2^x-3^x)^2}{1+\cos(x)-e^x-e^{-x}} = \frac{(x \ln(2/3) + o(x))^2}{-\frac{3x^2}{2}+ o(x^2)} = -\frac{2}{3}\ln^2\left( \frac{3}{2}\right) + o(1)$$

so the limit is $$-\frac{2}{3}\ln^2\left( \frac{3}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Is there Any Other Approach to solve this. Because I know how to solve by using Series of those expression?

Comment: @mathophile Without L'Hopital's rule, without series expansion... Maybe you should add to your question which method you allow....